# Updating grouper column based on specific column value in Scala/Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is what I am trying to accomplish using spark or scala+spark:

Each instance of "A", in column_1, signifies the start of a new group up until the next "A".  Trying to populate a "grouper" column.  I know that I can accomplish this in a very complicated way, using Nested Lists or loops but I just think their has to be a quicker way using spark. Or a simple combination of scala and spark that I am not thinking of or do not know about.

Below code is in MySql:

before:

```
column_1   grouper
A 
B
C
A
B
C
D
A
B

SELECT @x:=1;
UPDATE table SET grouper=IF(column_1='A',@x:=@x+1,@x);
```

after:

```
column_1   grouper
A          2 
B          2
C          2
A          3
B          3
C          3
D          3
A          4
B          4
```

What I have tried in Spark that would be similar to above with no success:

```
var group = 1

     val mydf4 = mydf3.withColumn("grouper", 
when(col("column_1").equalTo("A"),group=group+1).otherwise(group))
```

Comment: From the only details above Spark in general and Spark SQL in particular doesn't seem to be the match for the task.
Do you have enough data to process it with Spark? Did you try to rethink your processing task in a functional way, ie using reduce?

Comment: Not sure why this is being down voted.  I am trying to do this just using Scala.  Just seems overly complex for something so simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I accomplished in Scala

```
     //"A" ids ("A" signifies the start of a new row in final table)
     var insid = mydf2.filter("column_1='A'").select("id").collect().map(_(0)).toList


     //Add the last id of the table to insid to handle last record processing
     val lastLoop = mydf3.select("id").orderBy(desc("id")).limit(1).head()
     val lastId = lastLoop(0).toString.toLong 
     insid = insid :+ lastId

     //Grab all the ids to create grouper
     val allid = mydf3.select("id").collect.map(_(0)).toList

     //Declare vars needed in loop
     var listSpot : Int = 0
     var idWithGrouper = Map[Integer,Integer]()

     //Number of times to run loop for grouper
     val numOfIterations : Int = insid.length-1        

     //Looping through ids and assigning a grouper based on new INS
       1 to numOfIterations foreach { _ =>          

        val betweenOne = insid(listSpot).toString().toInt    
        val betweenTwoHelp = insid(listSpot+1)
        val betweenTwo = betweenTwoHelp.toString().toInt - 1

            for(id <- allid)
            {

            val id2 = id.toString().toInt            

                val m = id2 match 
                {
                case x if betweenOne until betweenTwo contains x => true
                case _ => false    
                }

                    if(m){idWithGrouper += ((id2,listSpot))}                                                                        
            }              

            listSpot+=1
        }    

      //Convert output map to df
      val grouperdf = idWithGrouper.toSeq.toDF("grouper_id", "grouper")

      //Combine grouperdf to original df
      val combineddf = mydf3.join(grouperdf, mydf3.col("id") === grouperdf.col("grouper_id"), "inner")         

      combineddf.createOrReplaceTempView("eight_three_four")
```